# Surface measure of a hypersurface

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

This is the problem I encountered. $S_{2n}$ is a hypersurface of $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ which is given by $\{(y_1,y_2,\cdots,y_{2n}):y_{2n}-y_{2n-1}+y_{2n-2}+\cdots+y_2-y_1=\zeta)\}$. Let $dS_{2n}$ be the surface measure on $S_{2n}$. Then is it true that $dS_{2n}d\zeta=dy=dy_1dy_2\cdots dy_{2n}$? Should there be a constant coefficient, like $\sqrt{n}$ added? Thank you for helping!

Comment: It look like $\zeta$ is a parameter, not a variable like the $2n$-$y$'s. I do not understand the $d\zeta$, then.

Comment: @Avitus, as you vary $\zeta$ you foliate (fill up nicely) $\mathbb R^{2n}$ with parallel hyperplanes.

Comment: @Ted I see: so we have a $family$ of hypersurfaces...now I understand, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need a constant. The orthogonal distance from the origin to this hyperplane is $\zeta/\sqrt{2n}$, so the volume element should be $dS_{2n}\,d\zeta/\sqrt{2n}$.

To respond to your further question, you probably won't like this answer. The usual way to get the area measure on a hypersurface is to take the volume element on $\mathbb R^N$ and contract it against the unit normal of the hypersurface. For example, for the plane $ax+by+cz=d$ in $\mathbb R^3$, $dS = (a\,dy\wedge dz + b\,dz\wedge dx + c\,dx\wedge dy)/\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}$. So in your case, it's going to be a sum of $2n$ terms if you want a coordinate expression in terms of the $y$-coordinates: 
$$\frac1{\sqrt{2n}}\sum_{i=1}^{2n} dy_1\wedge\dots\wedge\widehat{dy_i}\wedge\dots\wedge dy_{2n}$$ 
("hat" means omitted). I had thought you wanted this for conceptual applications (like something analogous to spherical coordinates).

Comment: Dear Ted, thank you so much for your answer. Could you please do me a favor by explaining in more details on how one is supposed to consider this kind of calculating surface measure, like giving the explicit expression of $dS_{2n}$? Thank you again!

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I need. So is there any standard references that involves this? I mean, is it the field of differential geometry or what else that deals with this sort of problems?

Comment: Yes, basics on differentiable manifolds. It's mostly at the level of exercises, so I can't suggest a reference offhand.